# 60s-70s Dystopian UK novel featured in the old Science Fiction Book Club

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

Looking for title/author of a 60's-70's novel of near future dystopian UK. It featured a family beset by "yobs" - that was the term actually used in the book. Yob culture was ascendant. There was a motorcycle gang that took over a young woman's family's house, and the novel ended with fundamentalists organizing throughout the country, fighting back and winning. Any ideas?

Also just remembered the fundamentalists dressed in robes like monks.

Comment: God, it's hard to Google for this one ... I keep finding Daily Mail articles about how the yobs are out to get everyone.

Comment: Was it by John Christopher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pendulum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0340020865) (1968) by John Christopher.

[image: Book cover]

As per [a review on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/809020860?book_show_action=true):

> A failing economy, rising permissiveness, youth violence and rampant disorder lead to the fall of government in the UK and rule by mobs of youth motorcycle gangs. An upper middleclass family suffers deprivations and the occupation of their home by one of these gangs as the pendulum of society swings away from disorder to the rise of a religious brotherhood that soon takes on the gangs and creates an equally unappealing future.

Comment: Can you explain why this book answers the question?

Comment: This book answers the question because it is the answer to the question! Thanks, espertus, I'm so pleased to know I'm not the only one who remembers this frightening glimpse that in some ways mirrors many things that are happening to Western culture right now.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Thank you for adding the detail to my answer. I didn't remember anything more than the name of the book.

Comment: No worries. It's almost a sort of a hobby for me, finding Link-only answers and adding summaries and cover images. However, I will note that there are a lot of people here who are adamant about such detail being present.